# Wrong data format in exported Excel

Tags: javascript, excel, formatting, js-xlsx, sheetjs

I ask help here about a trouble with [SheetJS js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) that [recently seems not to be supported actively](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues). I already put [an issue](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/1490).

The point is that I want to use non-English data format (dates and numbers). When I export to XLSX file, the library does not process correctly and the represented information in the exported Excel is wrong.

Comment: I think here you find many examples and explanations, even the thread is already old: https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/134

Comment: You should always separate data storage from data presentation. `HTML` is made for data presentation, not for data storage. And since you are using `angular-locale_es-es.min.js`, it is a special data presentation for Spain. The `Excel` export always should get it's data from the data storage and never from the data presentation. So `XLSX.utils.table_to_book` (convert `HTML` to `Excel`)  is a bad idea at all.

Comment: As you see, `HTML` does not have explicit date and number types. So it is totally not clear what date `2/1/19` shall be (MDY or DMY?) and whether `13/1/19` is a date at all. Also it is unclear what number `1.234` shall be (is `.` decimal seperator or thousands seperator?) and what number `123,4`shall be (is `,` decimal seperator or thousands seperator?). And since it is not clear, the defaults are English US: Dates are `MDY` and for numbers `.` is decimal seperator and `,` is thousands seperator.

Comment: David, I need the reverse process: from HTML table to Excel file. Take [an example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MdKawR).

Comment: AxelRichter, I know why the library is wrongly exporting. I only want to achieve a way to export non-English data from a HTML table (independently of its collection); i.e., the Excel has to be a "carbon copy" of the table.

Comment: "the Excel has to be a "carbon copy" of the table": So simply a `raw` text export? `XLSX.writeFile( XLSX.utils.table_to_book( $( '.table' ).get( 0 ), {raw:true}), 'Excel.xlsx' );`

Comment: This is an improvement, but the trouble is that Excel detects now as text plain, not numbers or dates.

Comment: Yes. But as far as I know, you have the following options: Either use raw export, then `XLSX.utils.table_to_book` exports all as plain text without parsing dates and numbers. Or use default inputs for dates and numbers, which are English US: Dates are `MDY` and for numbers dot is decimal seperator and comma is thousands seperator. Then `XLSX.utils.table_to_book` is able parsing dates and numbers to lead the export also to have dates and numbers instead of plain text only.

Comment: "That is, another problem with the Anglo-Saxon ethnocentrism in computing.":  No. As said it is a problem because of using `HTML` table input since `HTML` is data presentation but not date storage. Using other approaches, for example getting the data from a database (the same which feeds the `HTML`) and then using array of arrays input or array of objects input, this problem disappears since you are able better determining the format of the array items.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193154/discussion-between-miquel-al-vicens-and-axel-richter).

Comment: I just tested the solution from @ShaharHadas and it works, so please accept his answer. This issue is closed

Comment: It is not the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

My solution would be different.

Build the custom excel format in code.
Attached is an example, which I think you should be able to improve upon.

This is a simple rewrite of your `exportToXls` function:

```
    function exportToXls() {
        var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
        var ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(vm.list, {header: ["date", "number"], cellDates: true});

        // Headers
        ws['A1'].v='Fecha';
        ws['B1'].v='N.º';

        // Data
        for(var i = 0; i < vm.list.length; ++i) {
            ws[`A${i+2}`].z = 'd/m/yy';
        }
        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Somename');
        XLSX.writeFile( wb, 'Table.xlsx' );
    }
```

`$$hashkey` is due to Angular (uses it to scan for changes). If you'll use a separate method or variable to inject the data, as shown in the example below, the `$$hashkey` will not be present.

Here it is in action [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ShaharHD/pen/mYrpew).

Comment: This code works, it exports the dates in the correct format inverting `MM-DD-YYYY` into `DD-MM-YYYY`. This is the correct answer, I discourage further discussions on this topic.

Comment: This code works? What about table header names? And the third column ("$$hashKey")?

Comment: Fixed the answer. Headers - simple code override :)
$$hashkey is due to Angular. So you can't use the same data variable that angular uses.

Comment: Sorry to be picky, but this solution was not what I wanted to get. I need an automatic process, taking data from tables, and without patches or half-done improvisations.

Comment: As was explained before, HTML has it’s limitations (as it’s a presentation layer). The library can’t really know your encoding style for the dates - I have the exact problem with presenting date/time in a different char set even. As you might have seen, the library doesn’t even have an option for locality - as there are so many - and excel already does a pretty good job at it, so I’m assuming most people just inject the data from code, and automate the formatting like I showed in the function.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have all the information, so I'm taking a blind stab in the dark x2:

1) If the date is being returned as a string, you can try and parse it out using things like left, right, mid, len, etc., then re-arrange it using the Date function.

2) It's possible to change the base language of Excel, which has the effect of changing the date format being used. You can change to a version of Excel where things work, process there, then convert back to the original language, which will convert the file over.

Again, with a lack of information, and a lack of the business need for doing this, I can't give a better response

Comment: What you are saying does not work or it is not a nice solution. By the links I wrote, you have enough information for get this issue.